# Weak topology generated by $C(X,R)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Therefore, $X$ is comletely regular and $C(X,R)$ (the set of all bounded and continuous functions form $X$ to $R$) separates points. By using this information, how can we prove that the weak topology generated by $C(X,R)$ equals the given topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the given topology on  $X$. The weak topology on $X$ is the coarsest topology $\omega$ such that all $f \in C((X,\tau),\mathbb R)$ are continuous with respect to $\omega$. Thus a subbasis for $\omega$ is given by $S = \{ f^{-1}(U) \mid U \subset \mathbb R \text{ open, } f \in C((X,                \tau),\mathbb R)\}$. Clearly $S \subset \tau$, thus $\omega \subset \tau$. Now let $V \in \tau$. Since $V' = X \setminus V$ is closed, for each $x \in V$ there exists $f_x \in C((X,\tau),\mathbb R)$ such that $f_x(x) = 1$ and $f_x(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V'$. The set $U_x = f_x^{-1}(0,\infty))$ is in $S$ and has the property $x \in U_x \subset V$. Thus $V = \bigcup_{x \in V} U_x \in \omega$.